# SQL Connection creates excessive concurrent HTTP connections to the host

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I kept commenting parts of my PHP script till this is what I ended up with. This thing creates about 200 to 300 concurrent connections in under a minute to the SQL ip (checked from the gateway) and I don't understand why.
Shouldn't closing the SQL connection end the communication between the servers?

The php script is being called once a second via JavaScript, I'm the only user on the website.

PHP implementation of the sock (taken from the net, `fclose()` added as that's how I read socks are closed)

```
<?php 
$cookie="tD2h6";
$data = $_COOKIE[$cookie];
parse_str($data, $output);
$name = $output['name'];
$pass = $output['pass'];

$con=mysqli_connect("89.33.242.99","global","changeme","global");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?';

# Prepare statement 
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->errno . ' ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

# Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

# Execute statement 
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

if($row['password']===$pass && !empty($pass))
{
    $hisusername = $name;
    $hiscredits = $row['credits'];
    $hiseuro = $row['euro'];
}
else
{
    $hisusername = "Guest";
    $hiscredits = "0";
    $hiseuro = "0";
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users`");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE admlevel>0");
$num_admrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$data = array();
$i=1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jbchat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data[$i] = $row['string'];
    $i=$i+1;
}
for($i=7;$i>0;--$i)
{
    $jbchat = $jbchat . $data[$i] . "<br>";
}

unset($data);
$data = array();
$i=1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM frchat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data[$i] = $row['string'];
    $i=$i+1;
}
for($i=7;$i>0;--$i)
{
    $frchat = $frchat . $data[$i] . "<br>";
}

unset($data);
$data = array();
$i=1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM drchat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data[$i] = $row['string'];
    $i=$i+1;
}
for($i=7;$i>0;--$i)
{
    $drchat = $drchat . $data[$i] . "<br>";
}

unset($data);
$data = array();
$i=1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cschat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data[$i] = $row['string'];
    $i=$i+1;
}
for($i=7;$i>0;--$i)
{
    $cschat = $cschat . $data[$i] . "<br>";
}

$today = getdate();
$date = $today['mday'] . "/" . $today['mon'] . "/" . $today['year'];
if($today['minutes']>9)
$time = $today['hours'] . ":" . $today['minutes'];
else
$time = $today['hours'] . ":0" . $today['minutes'];

$sqlx = 'SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE username=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5'; 
# Prepare statement 
$stmt = $con->prepare($sqlx);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sqlx . ' Error: ' . $con->errno . ' ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}


# Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    if($row['read']==0)
        $nnumber = $nnumber+1;
    $notifications = $notifications . "
    <li>
    <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"invisphp2('http://r4ge.ro/php/readnotif.php?notifid=" . $row['id'] . "')\">
    <i class=\"fa fa-warning danger\"></i>" . $row['text'] . "
    <br>" . $row['date'] . "
    </a>
    </li>";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30");
    $data = array();
    $i=1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $data[$i] = $row['name'] . ": " . $row['msg'];
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    for($i=30;$i>0;--$i)
    {
        $lchat = $lchat . $data[$i] . "<br>";
    }


echo json_encode(array(
"registered" => $num_rows,
"admins" => $num_admrows,
"time" => $time,
"date" => $date,
"nnumber" => $nnumber,
"notifications" => $notifications,
"lchat" => $lchat,
"hisusername" => $hisusername,
"hiscredits" => $hiscredits,
"hiseuro" => $hiseuro
));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Edit: after listening to a comment that's now deleted, I removed every single query except the first one, so this code is now being ran, the connections still rocketed to 150 in 20-30 seconds.

```
<?php 
$cookie="tD2h6";
$data = $_COOKIE[$cookie];
parse_str($data, $output);
$name = $output['name'];
$pass = $output['pass'];

$con=mysqli_connect("89.33.242.99","global","changeme","global");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?';

# Prepare statement 
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->errno . ' ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

# Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

# Execute statement 
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

if($row['password']===$pass && !empty($pass))
{
    $hisusername = $name;
    $hiscredits = $row['credits'];
    $hiseuro = $row['euro'];
}
else
{
    $hisusername = "Guest";
    $hiscredits = "0";
    $hiseuro = "0";
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


echo json_encode(array(
"registered" => $num_rows,
"admins" => $num_admrows,
"time" => $time,
"date" => $date,
"nnumber" => $nnumber,
"notifications" => $notifications,
"lchat" => $lchat,
"hisusername" => $hisusername,
"hiscredits" => $hiscredits,
"hiseuro" => $hiseuro
));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing the object-oriented and non-object-oriented approaches?  You should probably just switch to PDO to avoid that kind of confusion since it only has the object-oriented approach.

Comment: should that matter? because there's no use in using param queries if there's no variable input. Please don't suggest PDO, the whole page is written using mysqli. Edit:: even like that, aren't these connections supposed to end once the php file reaches it's end?

Comment: I upvoted this because I'm curious if anyone know whether mixing the OOP and procedural approaches can somehow cause this.

Comment: You are still technically mixing them. `mysqli_close($con);` is procedural for `$con->close();`

Comment: `mysqli_connect_errno()` => `$con->connect_errno`

Comment: so replace mysqli_close with $con->close(); and the error thingy? edit:: I took everything from here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php . I don't get why using objects or variables should in any way affect how many connections are created.

Comment: Also, technically for OOP, instead of `$con=mysqli_connect(` it should be `$con= @new mysqli(`. This is why I said PDO is easier.  Mysqli is a mess of confusion due to having two ways to do everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this will make me look very bad.
Unfortunately there is nothing bad in this particular code.

The problem was at a much deeper level in the site's framework, and the above code being the homepage, lead me to think it was the source of the problem.

To @developerwjk , the answer is no, combining procedural and object oriented implementations has no effect whatsoever on the functionality of mysqli, it works great.

The culprit: lack of mysqli_close() at the end of every single PHP that creates a connection

Don't trust the documentation when it says the connection is closed on script end, put it there just to be safe.